# IE MIME/content filtering

Tags: internet-explorer-6, mime-filter

I'm looking into ways to develop an extension for IE6+ that will allow handling of custom MIME types.

As an example, I need to be able to take a document with a custom MIME type that is returned by the server, perform some processing on it, and then change the MIME type back to something that IE can natively handle, such as text/html or image/jpeg.

I am familiar with the urlmon MIME filters, but they have a huge weakness; they are only invoked for the top level document, and not for any of the additional page content such as images and the like.

The one way that I can think of that will work is to hook the HTTP/S protocol handlers using vtable/iat patches, similar to the way Google Gears works, to be able to intercept the response headers, and modify the headers and response body when a document with the specified MIME type is received.

I'm wondering if anybody else has any good ideas on how this could be accomplished in a less hacky/intrusive way.

Edit: 
Just thought I'd follow up on this and mention that I went with the vtable patch into the HTTP/S protocol handlers, and it worked much better than I expected. If anybody else is looking to do something like this, I highly recommend taking a look at the HttpHandlerPatch class in Google Gears for some inspiration.

Comment: Hi, I'm writing extension for IE that will block adverts. I need similar functionality like you - filtering MIME/content.
Unfortunately I don't have great experience in Windows C++ programming. Can you tell me some more about "vtable and iat patching." Is this the same as "API hooking"? Because I can't find much about 'vtable patching' in google. Do you have any good resources about this topic and how you did this content filtering?

I looked at this gears' HttpHandlerPatch class but right now it's to complicated to me.

Comment: Hi. What I mentioned there is fairly complicated. I eventually ended up going with some API hooking techniques to hook into the WinInet APIs, as it was cleaner and gave me more control. To be able to do what you want with this method is still not exactly simple, but it's not too bad. You can look into the Detours project by Microsoft Research for an API hooking library which should work for this, though I ended up rolling my own (though less flexible) version due to the steep price tag ($10,000+) for the commercial version of Detours.

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago, I wrote such extensions, BHO, IE toolbars, etc., based on a book called Shell Programming in VB6. The book I used is this one: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926707/ This book tells you how to hook and trap messages coming into IE. I wrote a kind of screen scraper (post-render style not like a spider that doesn't execute the javascript first). It was based on IE5 but the extensions still work with IE6. I probably still have the VB6 source somewhere. I am not offering to upgrade it to .Net for you though.

PS. The review on that page by Haroeris Astrum is by me :)