# How to detect image loading in Internet Explorer (and don't display it)?

Tags: c++, image, internet-explorer, bho

I'm writing a BHO add-on for Internet Explore (8 and 9). And I followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489%28VS.85%29.aspx) tutorial explaining how to write add-on that hides all images on page.
The problem is that these images are hid after the page is downloaded. So for a second there is the full page and then all images disappear.
I have to make it that when an user open the page there won't be any images even for a second.

I can't find proper event in DWebBrowserEvents2. Maybe I should look in IHTMLDocument2. I have no idea actually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try this one: DISPID_DOWNLOADBEGIN ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. This one gives me nothing. I don't know when it's fired exactly, usually there are two DownloadBegin events when you want to view new site.

Comment: Did you know Internet Explorer can already turn off images? (Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Show Pictures)

Comment: I'm not using IE daily ;) I'm writing add-on for blocking adverts, something like Adblock on Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this properly with IE. The DWebBrowserEvents events are fired too late for you to modify the DOM before the images are downloaded.

You'll see comments referring you to a Async Pluggable Protocol, a method of hooking into IE at a lower-level, but it's rather tricky and not recommended by Microsoft to do this for http/https. Check out the [MSDN IE Extension Developer forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/threads) for more discussion on this.

Comment: I've read about "Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols". But I thought I can write only custom protocol handlers as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspxProtocol.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DataProtocol.aspx). I thought I can't write it for HTTP because people are trying writing some hacks for what I want to achieve ( [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052141/ie-mime-content-filtering) ). Do you think that trying to write Asyncronous Pluggable Protocol for HTTP is what I need?

Comment: I accepted your answer. I'm eventually trying this "Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols" approach. It seems that it's the only way of doing filtering before downloading anything (except low-level API hooking).

Do You have any resources about doing APP with HTTP protocol?

Comment: Best post I've read was http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.mshtml_hosting/msg/7013a517c207d543?pli=1 and search for various other posts from Igor, who seems to be the only person in the world who knows how to do that stuff.

Comment: And did you used Igor's PassthruAPP from Google Gears? Or implemented your own APP for HTTP? What did you end up doing? I read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/a7ab3ecc-633c-4a9a-8290-bd6f34c41ada) thread and wonder if I should try to use PassthruAPP.